# How to perform password validations in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I have to perform validations on password and confirm password. This is my criteria for password field:

1. First letter should be capital.
2. Password should be more than above 6 values.
3. At least one special key should be present.
4. At least 1 numeric value should be entered in password.

If all this criteria are present then only password is accepted.

Comment: This can be closed under the official close reason of _Too Broad: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
- (BOOL)passwordIsValid:(NSString *)password {

    // 1. Upper case.
    if (![[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[password characterAtIndex:0]])
        return NO;

    // 2. Length.
    if ([password length] < 6)
        return NO;

    // 3. Special characters.
    // Change the specialCharacters string to whatever matches your requirements.
    NSString *specialCharacters = @"!#€%&/()[]=?$§*'";
    if ([[password componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:specialCharacters]] count] < 2)
        return NO;

    // 4. Numbers.
    if ([[password componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"]] count] < 2)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Testing it out:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self passwordIsValid:@"Test#one"] ? @"YES" : @"NO"); // Prints NO.
NSLog(@"%@", [self passwordIsValid:@"Test#1"] ? @"YES" : @"NO"); // Prints YES.
```

Comment: hi mortenfast ,this code is working for only  first 3 cases because the last case i need to check for is a numeric value must be mandatory and u r passing@"0123456789" which is a string .So please provide a solution.Thanks

Comment: Did you try it out? ;) The string @"0123456789" is used to feed the NSCharacterSet, so it knows what characters we regard as numbers. I don't know of other decimal numbers than 0-9, so the character set contains all valid numbers. If you test the method with @"Test#1" it will return YES, and @"Test#one" will return NO.

Comment: ya i tried it out but only first 3 cases are working

Comment: If I test with a password without numbers in it, the method returns NO. If I test with a password that has numbers in it, the method returns YES. Have I misunderstood the 4th criteria?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code: what you need to do is, just manipulate regular expressin according to your need,

```
-(IBAction)passwordValidator:(id)sender{
    NSString *pwd=[NSString stringWithString:passwordField.text];
    int lngth=[pwd length]; 
    int minlength=6;

    NSString *regex = @"\\b([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\b"; 

    NSPredicate * regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

    BOOL x= [regextest evaluateWithObject:pwd];

    if (lngth>=minlength) {
        NSLog(@"passoword length is enough");
        if (x==FALSE) {
            //DO something
        }
    }
    else {
        //DO other thing
    }
}
```

You Can Use [Following](http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/) set of validations.

Answer (score 0):

Use DHValidation for your all validations. It is much easier to use.